# Range of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x-y}+\ln(9-x^2-y^2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to find the range of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x-y}+\ln(9-x^2-y^2)$.

I know its domain is the set
$$x\geq y\quad\text{and}\quad x^2+y^2<9$$
I also know $\sqrt{x-y}\geq0$ and $\ln(9-x^2-y^2)>0$. So I may say the range is
$$f>0$$
Is it right?

Comment: Why you think that $\ln(9-x^2-y^2)>0$?

Comment: What does $f>0$ *mean*?

Comment: what happens to $\ln(x)$ as $x\to 0$ from the positive side? Other thoughts; individually,  the square root part maximises to $\sqrt 6$ in the rectangle $[-3,3]\times [-3,3]$, which is bigger than the circle you are in.  The natural large part maximizes to $\ln (9)$ in that rectangle. So clearly your range can go no higher than $\sqrt 6 + \ln (9)$.  It will be less than that because those maximums aren't achieved at the same place, plus you are working in the circle which is a subdomain of the square

Comment: Well, this is tagged as [multivariable-calculus], so presumably you know how to find extrema of multivariable functions. (Partial derivatives, Jacobian matrix/determinant etc. etc.) Presumably you have tried that and got stuck somewhere. You should rewrite the question to point to the particular problem that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, we need to discuss the *Domain* of your function $f$, which is
$$
D=\{(x,y)\subset \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2< 9, y \leq x\}.
$$

Clearly, $9-x^2-y^2$ can be as close to zero as we wish over $D$, so $f$ does not have a lower bound. Regarding the upper bound, it can be attained at a point on the line $y=x$, in which case the upper bound would be $\ln 9$, or at a critical point in the interior of $D$. If you run the calculations, you will see that the upper bound is $m = f(x^*,y^*)$, where $(x^*,y^*)$ is the critical point (you can compute it solving a nonlinear system of equations) and you'll conclude that the range is $(-\infty, m]$, with $m \approx 3.36729$.

Comment: @aschepler yes, you are correct. What is your point? I mentioned the line $y=x$ because there could be a global maximum at the boundary, that would not be a critical point.